# UICollectionView cell not align top with Navigation Bar

Tags: xcode, collectionview

I am new to Xcode, I have add a Navigation Controller to the project, and Add a collection view to a view controller, but the first cell always padding down, but when I remove the navigation controller, its return normal, Please help, Thanks.

p.s. sorry for no image present, my reputation not meet the requirement....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution, but don't know it is correct, It just simply set the navigation bar Translunt = false, then the view return normal, If there something wrong, please correct me, Thanks.